# quaternions for Opengl ES

Tags: animation, opengl-es, quaternions

I am working with Opengl es to create a stickman and this might seem like a stupid question but when using quaternions to represent rotation what should I do if want the rotation to be around another point than the origin and should I use a unit quaternion or not.
my guess is I can rotate and then translate too change the centre of rotation and I'm not going to use unit quaternions. Is this the right path?

Comment: Why would you not use a unit quaternion?

Comment: well the unit quaternion would give me rotation on a unit 3 dimensional sphere. And I guessed this is not what I want since the point I want to rotate is on an arbitrary sphere

Comment: An arbitrary quaternion doesn't offer enough degrees of freedom to rotate around an arbitrary point (it only offers one extra degree, whereas the point requires three). You can't avoid applying an offset as well.

Comment: ok, so I need to use a unit quaternion and apply an offset to the centre of rotation so I can get a rotation about that center?

Answer (score 1):

Like said in the comments, a non-unit quaternion does not magically rotate around an arbitrary point. So there is no need to use non-unit quaternions. What you need to do is, translate your rotation center to the origin, rotate about the origin with the quaternion as usual and then translate back to the rotation center.

If you want to really represent this whole transformation in a single mathematically clean construct, you can use dual quaternions, but I'm sure this will be overkill.

Comment: what I did is pretty simple actually. I took my euler angles transformed them into quaternions then applied rotation to a point by multiplying the quaternion to that point.

Comment: Yes, and? In your question you asked to rotate about an arbitrary point, so now you have to wrap this rotation between two translations, like said.

Comment: well that's the weird thing. let's say I want my centre of rotation to be (0,-2,0) and that the point I want to rotate is (1,0,0). all I have to do is translate the later to (1,-2,0) and the centre of rotation will automatically go from (0,0,0) to (0,-2,0). When I rotate my point(1,-2,0) 90° anti-clockwise about the y axis let's say it looks like it is rotating around (0,-2,0) instead of (0,0,0) this without any translation.

Comment: @Steve No, you translate by (0,2,0), so the point becomes (1,2,0) and the centre (0,-2,0) will move to (0,0,0). Then you rotate about the y-axis through the origin and the point becomes (0,2,-1). Then you translate back by (0,-2,0) and the point becomes (0,0,-1). In this case the translation was completely useless, as you translated along the rotation axis. So it is just the example that makes a translation unneccessary.

Comment: @Steve If it helped, up-voting (and maybe accepting) is appreciated.